# What is the output of applying the Hadamard matrix to $\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{xy}|y\rangle$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, hadamard

If, for some $x$, I have the $n$-qubit state
$$\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{xy}|y\rangle,$$
and I would like to apply to that the $n$-qubit Hadamard transform, with the aim of calculating the final state.

I understand I can continue like following:
$$\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n}\sum_{j\in\{0,1\}^n}(-1)^{xy}(-1)^{jy} |j\rangle
= \sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n}\sum_{j\in\{0,1\}^n}(-1)^{y(x+j)}|j\rangle, $$
but what cancels out here and why?

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: including text/math in figures is generally frowned upon

Comment: How are you editing your math equation?

Comment: @Ido you can see the source of your question by clicking on "edit". Math is added using [mathjax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/49/55). Also, you need to tag people using `@name` to make sure they get notified of your comment

Comment: @glS thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the identity
$$
\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{y\cdot z} = 2^n \delta_{z,0}
$$
with $z=x+j$. This identity is based on the fact that "summing $d$-th roots of unity gives zero" if $d>1$.

Then you see that the result of applying the Hadamard gate twice is indeed the input state:
$$
\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n} \sum_{j\in\{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{y\cdot (x+j)} |j\rangle = 2^n |x\rangle
$$
Note that usually the Hadamard gate is normalised by $2^{-n/2}$ for it to be unitary.

Remark: In higher-dimensional systems, $H\neq H^{-1}$, which you can see above since the identity would give you $j=-x$ which is only equal to $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$. There, the inverse has an additional minus sign in the exponent (well, and replace $-1$ by $e^{2\pi i/d}$).

EDIT: I was asked to elaborate on the sum of roots of unity. Let's show the following
$$
\sum_{y\in\mathbb{Z}_d^n} \omega^{y\cdot z} = d^n \delta_{z,0},
$$
where $d>1$ and $\omega$ is primitive $d$-th root of unity, e.g. $\omega=e^{2\pi i/d}$. Above, we have $d=2$. We have the following identity for the sum of all primitive $d$-th roots:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \omega^k = 0.
$$
I will not give a proof of this. It should be clear from the geometrical intuition, just think about the equidistant position of the roots of unity on the unit circle (cp. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)).
Next, we have to count how many times we get each root of unity in the second-to-last equation. If $z\neq 0$, there are $d^{n-1}$ possible solutions $y\in\mathbb{Z}_d^n$ to each of the linear systems $y\cdot z = k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}_d$. Clearly, the solution spaces are mutally disjoint and their union is $\mathbb{Z}_d^n$. Thus, any primitive root appears exactly $d^{n-1}$ times, and the sum is $d^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \omega^k = 0$. If $z=0$, however, any term is identically $1$ and the result is $d^n$.

PS: BTW, the matrix representation of the Hadamard gate is just the discrete Fourier transform; the math is the same.

Comment: Thank you! this helps so much.
Can you please elaborate on why 
$$
\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{y\cdot z} = 2^n \delta_{z,0}
$$
is correct?

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is enormously helpful!